# Need assistance regarding Core Motion

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-motion

Using core motion I get 3 values of yaw, pitch, roll, Now using these values I need to create a custom loader, when user moves device right, forward, left, backward this loader will fill. So I draw a circle using this core graphics method

```
void CGContextAddArc (
   CGContextRef c,
   CGFloat x,
   CGFloat y,
   CGFloat radius,
   CGFloat startAngle,
   CGFloat endAngle,
   int clockwise
);
```

In which all values are fixed and pass startAngle the value of pitch by calculating radian

```
myRadianMethod(myPitchValue)
```

Now when as I move the device circle starts filling but I want to make it fill in four moves Right, Forward, Left, Backward. How do I fine tune my code to accomplish this?

> Device movement is like...user is holding his/her iphone in landscape
>   position... now user first have to tilt device right and this will
>   fill some portion, now user will tilt iPhone towards himself this will
>   fill more, then user will tilt left and then back to complete the
>   fill...

Comment: Right, left, forward, and backward are many directions of motion. Pitch is just one direction of rotation, which doesn't involve moving the device anywhere. Can you clarify a bit, for example list the steps the user is supposed to perform and how the program should respond.

Comment: ... its like ... user is holding his/her iphone in landscape position... now user first have to tilt device right and this will fill some portion, now user will tilt iPhone towards himself this will fill more, then user will tilt left and then back to complete the fill...hope this clear

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMDeviceMotion_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CMDeviceMotion/rotationRate

RotationRate only reflects the changes in angles around the three axes. So each time there is a positive change in the direction you are awaiting you could sum these changes up to a certain value.

Is that what you are looking for?